# Logstash grok pattern issue

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, grok

I have been using logstash to read a log file in which I have come across with some difficulty in grokking the log statement.

The log pattern is like this

> "20160401-00:00:00","abc3ap5a","AB2","EAP-Production(Production/EAI)","160402.0","0.0","5.0",

and I have tried to grok like this

> "%{NOTSPACE:Datetime}","%{WORD:Hostname}","%{WORD:Location}","%{PROG:Usage)","%{NUMBER:YYMMDD}","%{NUMBER:HHMM}","%{NUMBER:CPU(%)}",""

Everything looks fine except when I try to run the conf file, it keeps saying

> The error reported is:
>     unmatched close parenthesis: /%{PROG:Usage)/m

I have tried to change the parenthesis for different kinds but the same error pops out. Would anyone can suggest any solution for me. What I need is to extract `EAP-Production(Production/EAI)` as a whole without changing the log file pattern.

Comment: Have you tried any grok debugger? You can try a grok debugger like : https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the closing parenthesis with a curly brace at the end

```
"%{PROG:Usage)"
```

should be

```
"%{PROG:Usage}"
```